# Simple way to test whether an element is in front?

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index

Two elements in a page have the same z-index...

```
<div id="one" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
<div id="two" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
```

Div two appears in front, because it follows after div one in the source.

In jQuery is there a simple way to test whether or not an element is in front of another element?

Comment: This might provide a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914457/determine-visibility-real-z-index-of-html-elements

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
I'm getting the offset of the passed element and comparing it to element I received from elementFromPoint.

```
function checkClickable(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var newElement = document.elementFromPoint(element.offsetLeft, element.offsetTop);
    if(newElement){
        if(newElement.id == id)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use this as a base.